# Coin Change Algorithm - DP with 1D array

Tags: dynamic-programming, coin-change

I came across a solution to the Coin Change problem here : [Coin Change](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-7-coin-change/). Here I was able to understand the first recursive method, the second method which uses DP with a 2D array. But am not able to understand the logic behind the third solution.

As far as I have thought, the last method works for problems in which the sequence of coins used in coin change is considered. Am I correct? Can anyone please explain me if I am wrong.

Comment: "the last method works for problems in which the sequence of coins used in coin change is considered" - not sure what that means. Can you elaborate ?

Comment: What I meant here is that the set of coins (1, 2, 1) is considered different from (1, 1, 2). Here the sum is same but while counting it is considered as different.

Comment: The [second line](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-7-coin-change/) says: "The order of coins doesn’t matter."

Comment: Yeah, that is what my question is. I am not able to understand why the third method works and calculates the answer when the order of coins doesn't matter.

Comment: Which part of the algorithm makes you feel that the order matters ?

Comment: The third part. I already have mentioned that in my question.

Comment: The third part is the algorithm, I asked which *part* of the algorithm makes you feel that there is meaning to the order of the coins in `S`.

Answer (score 1):

Well I figured it out myself!

This can be easily proved using induction. Let table[k] denote the ways change can be given for a total of k. Now the algorithm consists of two loops, one which is controlled by i and iterates through the array containing all the different coins and the other is the j controlled loop which for a given i, updates all the values of elements in array table. Now consider for a fixed i we have calculated the number of ways change can be given for all values from 1 to n and these values are stored in table from table[1] to table[n]. When the i controlled loop iterates for i+1, the value in table[j] for an arbitrary j is incremented by table[j-S[i + 1]] which is nothing but the ways we can create j using at least one coin with value S[i + 1] (the array which stores coin values). Thus the total value in table[j] equals the number of ways we can create a change with coins of value S[1]....S[i] (this was already stored before) and the value table[j-S[i + 1]]. This is same as the optimal substructure of the problem used in the recursive algorithm.

Comment: You mixed the indices a bit in your explanations but I think that you got it: `i` (row) represents the sub-sum, and `j` is the coin on index `j` in `S`. The cell `table[i][j]` represents the number of possible combinations of coins that sums to `i` which includes the coin `S[j]`. The table is built bottom-up, which means that the "sub-sums" are calculated on each iteration gradually, and the "recursive calls" instead of being calculated, are taken from the previously already calculated sub-sums. That's also why the final result will be on the last line after we finished iterating the last coin

Comment: The table is 1D and table[k] represents the number of ways to create change for a total of k. In the third algorithm, the 2D array is collapsed and  the 1D array is overwritten as the past data is no more needed. Your logic is right. Can you point where I have mixed the indices? I'll rectify them.

Comment: Just swap i with j (and vise verse) in the following section: "When the i controlled loop iterates for i+1, the value in table[j] for an arbitrary j is incremented by table[j-S[i + 1]] which is nothing but the ways we can create j using at least one coin with value S[i + 1] (the array which stores coin values). Thus the total value in table[j] equals the number of ways we can create a change with coins of value S[1]....S[i] (this was already stored before) and the value table[j-S[i + 1]]"

Answer (score 0):

```
int arr[size];
memset(arr,0,sizeof(size));
int n;
cin>>n;
int sum;
cin>>sum;
int a[size];
fi(i,n)
cin>>a[i];
arr[0]=1;
fi(i,n)
for(int j=arr[i]; j<=n; j++)
    a[j]+=a[j-arr[i]];
cout<<arr[n];
```

The array `arr` is initialised as 0 so as to show that the number of ways a sum of `i`can be represented is zero(that is not initialised). However, the number of ways in which a sum of 0 can be represented is 1 (zero way). 
Further, we take each coin and start initialising each position in the array starting from the coin denomination. 
`a[j]+=a[j-arr[i]]` means that we are basically incrementing the possible ways to represent the sum `j`by the previous number of ways, required (`j-arr[i]`).
In the end, we output the `a[n]`

Comment: Appreciate it `vaultah`